# "Multi-lingual Support" detection in Android

Tags: android

I am working on the new application and want to give users an option to change language based on their preference. At the same time, I don't want to show this options to such users whose device doesn't support multi-lingual. 
Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The base Android already allows the user to select their language system wide, so you don't need to duplicate this feature in your app, and all you need to do is to provide resources in multiple languages.  These will be picked up automatically by `Activity.getString()` and other resource aware routines.